# Enable/Disable OpenSSH daemon on an interface

Tags: ssh, openssh, sshd

I have multiple network interfaces like Ethernet, Wifi, WWAN etc.

I want to block SSH `root` login on all interfaces except for the Ethernet one.

Is there an interface-based configuration for `sshd`, like some setting in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`?

I could not find interface-based settings in the settings manual:
https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config

On my WWAN interface, I get attacks from intruders like these, which I want to avoid:

```
systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in OpenSSH Key Generation being skipped.
systemd[1]: Started OpenSSH Per-Connection Daemon (195.133.18.24:45650).
sshd[704]: Invalid user user from 195.133.18.24 port 45650
sshd[704]: error: Could not get shadow information for NOUSER
sshd[704]: Failed password for invalid user user from 195.133.18.24 port 45650 ssh2
sshd[704]: Received disconnect from 195.133.18.24 port 45650:11: Normal Shutdown, Thank you for playing [preauth]
sshd[704]: Disconnected from invalid user user 195.133.18.24 port 45650 [preauth]
systemd[1]: sshd@10-2.71.220.228:22-195.133.18.24:45650.service: Succeeded.
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a possible 'interface' based configuration for SSH daemon, like some setting in /etc/ssh/sshd_config?

Yes, in /etc/ssh/sshd_config you can specify the interface(s) on which your sshd service will listen to. The setting is called "ListenAddress".

If ListenAddress setting is not in the config, then the default is to listen on all local addresses.

Unfortunately, that setting can't take an interface name, but it can take the interface IP address (and port) -- which solves your problem. Example:

```
echo "ListenAddress 192.168.55.101:40022" >>/etc/ssh/sshd_config
/etc/rc.d/rc.sshd restart
```

Comment: `ListenAddress` (and `Port`) directives are **cumulative**, so in many cases, it may be better to **edit** `sshd_config` and search for any pre-existing directives, rather than unconditionally adding one to the pile.

Comment: @JimL. : Yes, editing the config is the proper thing to do.  I just gave him a quick hack to point him in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Use a firewall rule – for example, nftables or iptables. (Firewalld may also be able to do this with "zones".) This is the most versatile option; both nftables and iptables support wildcards, and both actually prevent connections *from* the incorrect interface (which is not relevant against internet bots, but can be relevant when guarding against malicious local users on wlan0).

- For example, in nftables you would write:

  ```
  table inet filter {
      chain input {
          [...]
          tcp dport 22 iifname "eth*" accept
          tcp dport 22 reject
          [...]
      }
  }
  ```
- In iptables `.rules` files, the same is:

  ```
  [...]
  -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -i eth+ -j ACCEPT
  -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j REJECT
  [...]
  ```

---

Your system uses per-connection sshd instances ("inetd style" or "socket activated") rather than the usual standalone daemon. In this mode, the listen addresses are not decided by the sshd but by the supervisor (super-server).

With systemd socket activation, run `systemctl edit --full sshd.socket` to define the listen addresses, replacing the existing ListenStream= options with:

```
[Socket]
ListenStream=192.168.55.101:22
```

Alternatively, you can keep the global ListenStream=, but bind the socket to only a specific interface (exact name only, wildcards not allowed):

```
[Socket]
ListenStream=0.0.0.0:22
ListenStream=[::]:22
BindToDevice=eth0
```

Afterwards, restart `sshd.socket` to apply the changes.

Note that this inetd-mode is generally not recommended for sshd, as the bruteforce bots may cause systemd's rate-limiting to kick in and prevent you from making even legitimate connections. You should consider disabling sshd.socket and enabling the "standalone" sshd.service instead. (After doing so, the listen addresses will be controlled by `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` instead.)